# How can I make different rails sites interact with each other?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm a website designer who's fairly new to rails. I'm building a custom CMS for the websites I design.

The idea is that clients will be able to login to their cms panel (on their individual domain and hosting) and can submit a support ticket which will be forwarded to my admin panel on my domain and hosting.

Is anyone aware of a learning resource for this type of function?

Any advice would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Rails is primarily built to handle web requests, so that's the most straightforward way to interact between Rails apps. Just create a post request containing the ticket info, targeted at your admin panel app, which has the typical Rails setup to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Rails uses helpers called `routes` to efficiently handle form submissions.  Instead of the expected `route` any `form_for @mymodel` can specify a url to send the form to, ostensibly to an offsite url as you desire.